# How I filter data from an input using vue/vuex?

Tags: vue.js, filter, vuejs2, vuex, computed-properties

I would like to know how through an input how I can filter data that comes from a computed property.

My problem comes from property computed dataFiltered () where a getter is returned but it has a string as parameter.

I would like that through an input when writing a word the information is filtered.

**Home.vue**

```
  </template>
     <input type="text" :v-model="search" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
      <div>
        <ul v-for="item in dataFiltered" :key="item.id">
         <li>{{item}}</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
 </template>

  <script>
     import {ACTYPE} from '../store/types/actions_types';
     import {mapState , mapGetters} from 'vuex';

     export default {
        name: 'home',
        created(){
        this.$store.dispatch(ACTYPE.GET_MOVIES);
     },
    data(){
      return{
        search: ''
      }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapState(['topMovies' , 'loading']),
      ...mapGetters(['filterData']),

      dataFiltered(){
        // parameter harcored
        return this.filterData("Sp")
      }
    },
   }
  </script>
```

**store/getters.js**

```
export const getters = {
  TopMovies: (state) =>{
    return state.topMovies.map(data =>{
      return data
  });
 },

filterData: (state) => (search) =>{
  let query = new RegExp(search , 'i');
  console.log(query);
  //return state.topMovies.filter(data => data.name === query);    
  return state.topMovies.filter(data =>{      
    return data.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  })
 },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your `:v-model="search"` should just be `v-model="search"`. `:v-model` is binding the value to something.

Secondly, I do not see you passing the `search` in the component to the Vuex store which is then applied in the getters.

---

This is not tested and I do not think you require the store for this to work. The most you may require the store is to fetch the initial data using the `mapGetters` helper and assuming `topMovies` in this case.

In your computed property, all you need to do is to filter the data using the search query string.

E.g.

```
computed() {
  ...mapGetters(["topMovies"]),
  filteredData() {
    return this.topMovies.filter(movie => movie.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ru Chern Chong For some reason he shows me all the data before making the query. When I'm doing the query, then the data is filtered.

There is no way to not show any data, until a query is added to the search?

Comment: That is possible, means you have to store the search query in the store and filter it directly in the getters first before calling it in your component.